# map function to work with event.target.name, have multiple values tagged to index of map

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, map-function

The below functionality is only capable of running only one component (i.e. "ComponentTwo"), I want to modify it to have more component, but issue is as i am using map function to loop through component to map "value", same value will be passed to all the component.
In the code there is two function for handling the change currently i am using the "handleInputChange" which take value as input but i want it to work with name so that i can have name to distinguish between components, below is one commented function which i am trying to implement, but is not working.

p.s. if you need any clarifications let me know in comment section.

link to code:https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hugle-mfstd?file=/src/App.js

```
 import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
    
    
    export default function App() {
        const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState(["Test"]);
    
        const addNewInputvalue = () => {
            setInputValues((prev) => {
                return [...prev, ""];
            });
        };
    
        const removeInput = (index) => {
            setInputValues((prev) => {
                const copy = [...prev];
                copy.splice(index, 1);
    
                return copy;
            });
        };
    
        // const handleChange = (event) => {
        //     event.persist()
        //     setData(prev => ({ ...prev, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }))
        // }
    
        const handleInputChange = (index, value) => {
            setInputValues((prev) => {
                const copy = [...prev];
                copy[index] = value;
                return copy;
            });
        };
    
        const consoleAllValues = () => {
            console.log(inputValues);
        };
    
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={addNewInputvalue}>New Input</button>
                {inputValues.map((val, i) => {
                    return (<div>
                        <ComponentTwo
                            key={i}
                            index={i}
                            value={val}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            removeInput={() => removeInput(i)}
                        />
                        <ComponentThree />
                        <ComponenFour />
                    </div>
                        >
            );
                })}
                <button onClick={consoleAllValues}>console log all values</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    const ComponentTwo = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Input: {props.index}</p>
                <input
                    name={"right_value"}
                    onChange={(e) => props.onChange(props.index, e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    value={props.value}
                />
                <button onClick={props.removeInput}>Remove Input</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array to store your values, you should create a key value object. See the changes I've made regarding your state, the way you iterate through the object inside your return statement and all the functions that manipulate your state.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
    const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
      'componentTwo': 'val1',
      'componentThree': 'val2',
      'componentFour': 'val3',
    });

    const addNewInputvalue = (name, value) => {
        setInputValues((prev) => {
            return {
              ...prev,
              [name]: value,
            }
        });
    };

    const removeInput = (name) => {
        setInputValues((prev) => {
            const copy = {...prev};
            delete copy[name];

            return copy;
        });
    };

    const handleInputChange = (name, value) => {
        setInputValues((prev) => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            [name]: value,
          };
        });
    };

    const consoleAllValues = () => {
        console.log(inputValues);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={addNewInputvalue}>New Input</button>
            {Object.keys(inputValues).map((name, i) => {
                return (<div>
                    <ComponentTwo
                        key={name}
                        index={i}
                        value={inputValues[name]}
                        onChange={(value) => handleInputChange(name, value)}
                        removeInput={() => removeInput(name)}
                    />
                    <ComponentThree />
                    <ComponenFour />
                </div>
                    >
        );
            })}
            <button onClick={consoleAllValues}>console log all values</button>
        </div>
    );
}

const ComponentTwo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Input: {props.index}</p>
            <input
                name={"right_value"}
                onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                value={props.value}
            />
            <button onClick={props.removeInput}>Remove Input</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```